# Recurrence relation with variable expressed in terms of n

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

I wrote a recursive algorithm which runs in `Θ(n)`.

One of the recurrence equations for `n > 0` is `T(n) = T(v) + T(n - 1 - v) + c` where `c` is a constant and `v` is a variable that can have values in the fixed range `n > v > 0`.

How do I go about solving or correctly simplifying this equation further?

Comment: If the value of `v` approaches the midpoint of the range `(0, n)`, the complexity will be `O(log(n))` and when the value of `v` is at the corner of this range, the complexity will be `O(n)`.

Comment: Without knowing more about v it's not possible to solve this recurrence. What do you know about v? Where did this recurrence come from?

Comment: @templatetypedef The algorithm is used to process binary trees. The raw, unsimplified equation would be `T(n) = T(n-L-1)+T(n-R-1)+c` where `L` is the left sub-tree (rooted at the left child node), and `R` is the right sub-tree (rooted at the right child node) of the root node that is being processed.  Since `R = n-1-L` and `L = n-1-R` (where `n` is the total number of nodes in the sub-tree and `1` stands for the root node), the equation can be simplified as `T(n) = T(n-L-1) + T(n-(n-1-L)-1) + c = T(n-L-1) + T(L) + c` which is equivalent to `T(n) = T(R) + T(n-1-R) + c`.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeatedly expand the non-constant term:

[image]

The series terminates when:

[image]

This means that [image], as the term `T(v)` will cancel with the denominator in `N`.

Comment: Does this solution account for the fact that `v` can vary with each recursive call of this type (depending on the topology of the subtree the call is being made on)? Or does it assume that `v` is going to be a constant during a single execution of the algorithm?

Comment: Yes, as the denominator will then be the sum of all `Vi`'s, and the sum of `T(Vi)` will _still_ cancel the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you described the behavior of your algorithm as follows: it does a constant amount of work on an empty tree and otherwise does a constant amount of work, then processes the left and right subtrees recursively. Rather than describing the runtime with a recurrence relation like the one you described, you can account for the runtime in a different way: the work done is directly proportional to the number of nodes in the tree, since you can charge each unit of work done to a specific node. As a result, the total runtime is O(n).

Comment: No offense, but you're kind of stating the obvious. My task is to write a complete theoretical analysis of the algorithm, so I need the recurrence relation to describe (and prove) the time complexity.

Comment: Note that a recurrence relation is only one way to have a complete theoretical analysis of a result. Having studied algorithms for a while and read a lot of papers, I'm relatively confident that an argument like this one would be totally fine.